# How to change Kendo Wizard Form data?

Tags: jquery, forms, kendo-ui, progress, wizard

I have a Kendo Wizard (jQuery) with 4 steps, each step has a Kendo form on it and used to Insert new data. Now, I want to use the same wizard to update data.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a unique class to each step. Then you use the setOptions Method to update the data.

```
    $("#wizard").kendoWizard({
        steps: [
        {
            title: "Initial step",
            className: "customOne"
        },
        {
            title: "Second step",
            className: "customTwo"
        },
        {
            title: "Third step",
            className: "customThree"
        },
        {
            title: "step end",
            className: "customFour"
        }
        ]
    });

var form = $(".customOne .k-form").getKendoForm();
form.setOptions({
    orientation: "horizontal"
});
```